# Weak Normalization of Beta-Reduction on typable lambda-terms

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have to directly show weak normalization of the β-reduction on typable λ-terms, without showing (a property that entails) strong normalization.

Hint: an idea analogous to that for the cut elimination procedure in the book (First-Order Logic and Automated Theorem Proving, by Melvin Fitting) works, judiciously choosing a β-reduction step among the possible ones and showing that that decreases some measure.

Comment: There are many type systems for the lambda-calculus. Which one you refer to?

Comment: well, I'm not sure. But I guess its the simply-typed

Comment: If you don't make explicit what is your type system, it is difficult to answer. Different type systems behave in very different ways.